# Upload CSV file to mysql from external URL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-sheets

For example I have an url from google sheets that exports a sheet to a CSV file:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}
```

I want some sort of mechanism to process the external CSV file to insert into a table in MySQL.

I haven't the slightiest idea on where to begin.

Update 25/03/2019: This is my most recent progress, thanks to some of the answers! I still have to get the CSV into MySQL.

```
 <?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$array = str_getcsv(file_get_contents("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...."));

var_dump($array);

    $name = tempnam('/','csv');
    $fp = fopen($name, 'w'); 

    // $array = str_replace('"', '', $array);

   fputs($fp, implode($array, ',')."\n");


$sql = "DELETE FROM conceptos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL 
    INFILE '$name' INTO TABLE conceptos FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";

fclose($fp);

?>
```

I am creating a temp file now to attempt to use LOAD DATA, however I have been getting different errors such as File not found, I have been able to see this only from the command line, and not directly from my php code.

Comment: This file comes from an external url to be parsed directly into php to insert into a table. I haven't come to the answer yet as to where to begin.

Comment: Is the download working? You _probably_ don't want to actually create a local file but instead open a connection to the database and write directly there.

But I would be surprised if you can open that spreadsheet without authentication.

If you're not seeing an error, the absolute #1 step you need to make right now is change the PHP error settings to display absolutely every error. Otherwise you are driving blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like 3 steps to me.

1. Query the URL and read the result into a string variable. (see here: [website query, php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583154/website-query-php))
2. Parse the string containing CSV data (see here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)
3. Insert into your MySQL database (see here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)

Parse like this:

```
<?php 
$Data = str_getcsv($CsvString, "\n"); //parse the rows 
foreach($Data as &$Row) $Row = str_getcsv($Row, ";"); //parse the items in rows 
?>
```

Good luck!

Comment: You were right, the first two steps were resolved in a single line as  str_getcsv(file_get_contents("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{key}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv&sheet={sheet_name}")); Now I am stuck at step 3.

Comment: See my edit, if you parse like that you will iterate over the lines of the csv, having $Row array for each line. Then it's just a matter of executing an insert statement for each row.